# Informative stacktraces with karma+browserify, how?

Tags: karma-runner, browserify

I have a problem with `assertion` traces - they are not enough informative.

For an instance `assertion fault`:

```
should navigate inside of layout
       PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0)
          1) serialize@http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/mocha/mocha.js?0491afff0b566ea45cd04c9164a355dba705689e:10776:34
             processAssertionError@node_modules/karma-mocha/lib/adapter.js:59:50
             node_modules/karma-mocha/lib/adapter.js:129:49
```

I've tried `karma-sourcemap-loader`, but it does not affect the output for me.
My config:

```
frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai', 'source-map-support', 'browserify'],
files: [
  'tests/**/*.js'
],
browserify: {
  debug: true
},
preprocessors: {
  'tests/**/*.js': ['browserify']
},
reporters: ['progress', 'nyan'],
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like problem related to `source-maps` support by different browsers, this configuration works just fine with `chromium` browser, but does not provide readable stack-trace information when i'm testing with `phantomjs` browser.